# Sending a file from an html input to a WebApi with Ajax - Encoding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, character-encoding

I have a `input` tag with `type="file"` and a function that uses Ajax to send the file to a Webapi endpoint.

```
$('#myInput').change(function () {
    if (this.files[0] === undefined) return;
    sendToWebapi(this.files[0]);
    this.value = null;
});

function sendToWebapi(file) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: "myWebApiPath",
        contentType: "text/csv",
        processData: false,
        method: "POST",
        data: data
    });
}
```

My issue is that French characters are not properly encoded when sent to the WebApi. See below an extract of the Request Body:

```
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryggBmtBMylhc9eoIE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

Date;Pi�ce;Journal;Libell�;D�bit;Lettrage;Cr�dit;Solde
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting charset explicitly:

```
function sendToWebapi(file) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: "myWebApiPath",
        contentType: "text/csv;charset=ISO-8859-1",
        processData: false,
        method: "POST",
        data: data
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that while adding charset explicitly resulted in my Request Body being properly displayed, my endpoint still views the strings as before.

Comment: @François What do you mean with "my endpoint still views the strings as before"?

Comment: Myenpoint signature is Task MyEndpointAsync([FromBody]List<MyCsvRow> rows). Then each row in rows see things like D�bit.

Comment: I think my issue is now a .Net Core 2 encoding issue and I should open a new question.